# Converting Javascript 1.7+ to Javascript 1.6

Tags: javascript, generator

Are there any converters or techniques available for converting Javascript 1.7 code with its new language features to Javascript 1.6?

I'm most interested in iterator generators and the `yield` keyword. The script engine I use is only 1.6, but iterator generators would make for much better code. Writing it by hand seems complicated.

I've tried writing it in C#, decompiling with ILSpy, and porting *that* to Javascript by hand.  But that's a damn mess.

I've searched for such a convertor, but I've found nothing - perhaps due to the search terms being shared with irrelevant results in this case.

Comment: I can only think of re-writing the generators by hand as lambda-functions so their variables don't pollute the scope

Comment: 1.6? Which environment uses that engine? The only one I know of is Firefox 1.5.

Comment: @uosɐſ How do you know it's 1.6? Since this is a Google product, I expect it to have the same JS engine as Chrome. **Actually, this entire JavaScript version numbering is in regard to Mozilla's JS implementation only.** Unless Google Apps Script implements Mozilla's JS engine, the versioning doesn't apply.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=418, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279357/is-there-a-complete-definition-of-the-google-app-script-syntax-somewhere

Comment: @uosɐſ I'll repeat myself. The JavaScript version numbering applies to Mozilla's JS engine exclusively. Using those version numbers in your question only adds confusion. What you want is simple: a polyfill for generators, and `yield`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Tell me, which is the more likely available project:  A compiler of 1.7 to 1.6 code for general backwards compatibility or specifically another language compiler that only adds to Javascript polyfill for generators and yield?

Comment: @uosɐſ More likely than both of those is a compiler of ES6 to ES5 code, since ECMAScript is the actual JavaScript standard, while "JavaScript" is only Mozilla's implementation of that standard. Notice how "JavaScript" confusingly has two meanings: (1) Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript, and (2) ECMAScript itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19685/discussion-between-uosa-and-sime-vidas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for you. Check out Traceur. It's a ES6 transpiler, i.e. it converts ES6 code (with all of the ES6 upcoming stuff like generators, classes, modules, `yield`) to ES5 code which is what today's JS engines are able to interpret.

Check it out here: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/

Language features page: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures

Notice how most of the stuff that Mozilla's been adding to JavaScript 1.7+ is being standardized in the upcoming edition 6 of the ECMAScript standard. The current edition is edition 5 which already contains some of that stuff (e.g. Array iteration methods, the Object Extensibility API).

Comment: Cool! Could you show us an example of the ES5 code that is generated for iterator/generators?

Comment: @Bergi I've made a jsFiddle from the generators demo available on the Traceur "language features" page. I don't understand the demo-code (e.g. `function*`, `yield`, `yield*`), but the demo lays out how Traceur can be used. 1. Put ES6 code in a `<script type="text/traceur">` element. 2. Include `traceur.js`, and `bootstrap.js` (available in the Traceour repo). **Demo is here:** http://jsfiddle.net/8ebGb/3/

Comment: @Bergi I've set up a playground on jsFiddle for writing and testing ES6 code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ebGb/5/