# JWT for Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, javascript

I'm using an API that requires a JSON Web Token generated with a couple of specific and unique parameters. In node, one would simply use `var jwt = require(jsonwebtoken')` to load the proper library, but that can't be done in Apps Script.

Is there a GAS library that could substitute node's jsonwebtoken module?

Comment: Does the API in question provide documentation on how to generate a JWT?

Comment: @DimuDesigns only for Java, Ruby, Python, and Node. Google Apps Script is a JavaScript framework, but many functions are disabled, such as the require function.

Answer (score -1):

On Google Apps Script server side code can "require" code only from other Google Apps Script project. For details see [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries).

Related Q&A

- [Is there a complete definition of the Google App Script Syntax somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12279357/1595451)
- [Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451)