# Google Apps Script throws error when trying to call Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Apps Script doesn't appear to recognize the function `Object.assign()`. When trying to use it I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function assign in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }
```

The code I'm testing the function with is the example copied directly from MDN:

```
function myFunction() {
  const object1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  };

  const object2 = Object.assign({c: 4, d: 5}, object1); //error is thrown here

  console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
  // expected output: 3 5
}
```

I copy-pasted the above code directly into the Chrome developer console, which ran fine and gave the expected output.

I can't find anything online saying that this particular function is not supported by apps script, or anything like that. So, what's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279357/is-there-a-complete-definition-of-the-google-app-script-syntax-somewhere , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768501/google-apps-script-javascript-standard-support , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252409/which-edition-of-ecma-262-does-google-apps-script-support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apps Script is **NOT** (as of this writing) a full implementation of the Ecmascript standard and currently does not natively support `Object.assign()`. However, you can leverage polyfills (when viable) that can add the needed functionality.

There is a polyfill available for `Object.assign()` on MDN at the following link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

**Note:** Rumor has it that Apps Script will be upgraded (at some point in the near future) to use Chrome's V8 engine thereby supporting EcmaScript 2017.

Comment: It is supported now https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Comment: For me it still doesn't work. I used `for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj2)) obj1[key] = val;` instead.